# Should i copy all the foreign keys from the main fact table to other related table?

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, cube

i have one main fact table, which contains about 10 foreign keys. now i have other 4 fact tables which has N:1 relationship connecting to the main fact table.
the question is, should i copy all of the foreign keys to these 4 fact tables, or should i do runtime join to the main fact table during SSAS cube processing?

what's the pros and cons?

Comment: can you give an example. It would be easier to analyze

Comment: sure. the main fact table is  
FactTable(PKey, FKey1,FKey2,FKey3,FKey4, Value)  
The related fact table like   
FactTable1(PKey, FactTable.PKey, ErrorCounter)  
FactTable2(PKey, FactTable.PKey, EventCounter)  

the question is, should i change FactTable1 or FactTable2 to structure like this:  
FactTable1(PKey, FactTable.PKey,FactTable.FKey1,FactTable.FKey2,FactTable.FKey3,FactTable.FKey4, ErrorCounter)

Comment: How can you have 4 fact tables that have a many to one relationship with another fact? By definition, fact tables are related by common dimensions. You don't put a fact key on another fact table except in very very limited circumstances.

Comment: Actually, when you try to implement many-to-many scenario, this is quite common. Suppose the main FactTable is FactConversation, and you may have FactActivity(and the coresponding dim table DimActivity)。In one conversation, you can have many activity. Now you want to know every activity 's conversation count, or conversation average duration. You would have to implement many-to-many between DimActivity and FactConversation

Answer (score 0):

Seems i can't add linebreak in comment. so i leave comments here.
sure. the main fact table is
FactTable(PKey, FKey1,FKey2,FKey3,FKey4, Value)
The related fact table like
FactTable1(PKey, FactTable.PKey, ErrorCounter)
FactTable2(PKey, FactTable.PKey, EventCounter)

the question is, should i change FactTable1 or FactTable2 to structure like this:
FactTable1(PKey, FactTable.PKey,FactTable.FKey1,FactTable.FKey2,FactTable.FKey3,FactTable.FKey4, ErrorCounter)

Answer (score 0):

For what reason would you want to put it all in one fact table? How do they relate in SSAS as measures/groups.

Are you having performance issues as it is now? If it takes 5 seconds more to process the cube when it's in separate tables, and it takes 5 minutes of ETL to load it all in one table, it'd be wiser to keep it as is. If it's the other way, maybe it'll be good to put it all in one fact table.

How you model your cube in SSAS with relations between Dim and Fact doesn't necessarily have to be the same way your tables relate to eachother in the relational database.

Comment: In my cube model, all the fact will have regular relationship to all the dim. so in my current relational db schema, i create a view for each of the related fact table, and join the main table to get those foreign keys.   i bind these views directly in my SSAS DSV.   what i care about is performance, both cube process and ETL. Is it wise to put all those keys into all that related tables during ETL. i did some simple test, which shows not that big a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is your goal and space is not an issue and you will be reporting from the child fact tables without referring the parent table, then sure, add the FK's to the other FACT tables, lost nothing and potentially gained a bit of speed.

However, If you always include the parent fact table when querying the related tables then there is no point (because you are always doing the join and incurring the cost of doing so)